# Can I give something using my iTunes gift card?

Tags: itunes

I want to give **an itunes movie** to a friend but can I use the credit I have on my iTunes gift card?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to click the **present** option or **give to a friend** or whatever it is called.
You pay, so it works without any problem.

Why would you think using a prepaid card like that does not work? It's a great method used  worldwide by people who don't have a credit card, or do not want to  link them.

Comment: You'd think so, but alas, it's not true. :(

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only use "the payment method that you have on file for your Apple ID."

https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201783

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7189394